# Java: How to get xml nodes path

Tags: java, xml

I have following  xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<RootNode>
 <Node_11>LEVEL_1-Value_1</Node_11>
 <Node_12>LEVEL_1-Value_2</Node_12>
 <Node_13>
    <Node_121>LEVEL_2-Value_1</Node_121>
 </Node_13>
 <Node_14>
    <Node_121>
        <Node_1231>
            <Node_12341>LEVEL_4-Value_1</Node_12341>
            <Node_12342>LEVEL_4-Value_2</Node_12342>
            <Node_12343>LEVEL_4-Value_3</Node_12343>
        </Node_1231>
    </Node_121>
 </Node_14>
 <Node_15>
    <Node_25>
        <Node_251>Value_251</Node_251>
        <Node_252>Value_252</Node_252>
    </Node_25>
    <Node_25>
       <Node_251>Value_253</Node_251>
       <Node_252>Value_254</Node_252>
    </Node_25>
    <Node_25>
        <Node_251>Value_255</Node_251>
        <Node_252>Value_256</Node_252>
    </Node_25>
    <Node_25>
        <Node_251>Value_257</Node_251>
        <Node_252>Value_258</Node_252>
    </Node_25>
 </Node_15>
</RootNode>
```

I have to print nodes path with value using java. Here is the sample of output I have to get:

```
RootNode.Node_11 = LEVEL_1-Value_1
RootNode.Node_12 = LEVEL_1-Value_2
RootNode.Node_13.Node_121 = LEVEL_2-Value_1
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231.Node_12341 = LEVEL_4-Value_1
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231.Node_12342 = LEVEL_4-Value_2
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231.Node_12343 = LEVEL_4-Value_3
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_251
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_252 = Value_252
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_253
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_252 = Value_254
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_255
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_252 = Value_256
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_257
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_252 = Value_258
```

Here is my last java code. I cannot get it work correctly.

```
public class Read_XML {
 static String rootTag = "";
 static HashMap valueMap = new HashMap();
 public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, AxiomRuntimeException
 {

    File inFile = new File("C:/Test.xml");

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(inFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String sXML = "";
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine())!= null;)
    {
        sXML += line;
    }
    Document doc = XMLStringParser.parseString(sXML);
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    rootTag += root.getTagName();
    NodeList rootList = doc.getElementsByTagName("RootNode");
    Element rootList_node = (Element) rootList.item(0);
    NodeList kids = rootList_node.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < kids.getLength(); i++)
    {
        String nextTag = "";
        if(kids.item(i) instanceof Element)
        {
            nextTag = rootTag + "." + kids.item(i).getNodeName();
            int level = 0;
            processChildNode(kids.item(i).getChildNodes(), nextTag, level);
        }
    }
    Iterator it = valueMap.keySet().iterator();
    for (;it.hasNext();)
    {
        String key = it.next().toString();
        String val = valueMap.get(key).toString();
        System.out.println(key + " = " + val );
    }
}

public static void processChildNode(NodeList listOfNodes, String tags, int level)
{
    String tagPath = tags;
    int curLevel = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfNodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Node Name = " + listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeName());
        if(listOfNodes.item(i) instanceof Element)
        {
            if(curLevel == level + 1)
            {
                tagPath = tags;
            }
            else
            {
                curLevel = level +1;
                tagPath += "." + listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeName();
            }
            if(listOfNodes.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength() >= 1)
            {
                processChildNode(listOfNodes.item(i).getChildNodes(), tagPath, curLevel);
            }

        }
        else if(listOfNodes.item(i) instanceof Text && listOfNodes.getLength() == 1)
        {
            String value = listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            valueMap.put(tagPath, value);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

Here is the current output :

```
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_251
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231.Node_12341 = LEVEL_4-Value_1
RootNode.Node_12 = LEVEL_1-Value_2
RootNode.Node_15 = Value_258
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231 = LEVEL_4-Value_3
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25 = Value_252
RootNode.Node_11 = LEVEL_1-Value_1
RootNode.Node_15.Node_251 = Value_257
RootNode.Node_13.Node_121 = LEVEL_2-Value_1
```

Please help me to make it work.
Thanks.

Comment: please explain why your code doesn't work properly. what is wrong with it to make it easier for us.

Comment: It produce wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

You have this problem because you use a `HashMap` for storing your values. As for example the path `RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_252` is present several times, the old value is erased when you put a new one in the Map.

You can replace your `HashMap` with a `List` in order to see all the found paths. See this example :

```
static List<String []> valueList = new ArrayList<String []>();
```

and you add the values this way :

```
valueList.add(new String [] {tagPath, value});
```

Finally, you can display your paths as follows :

```
Iterator<String []> it = valueList.iterator();
for (;it.hasNext();) {
    String [] val = it.next();
    System.out.println(val[0] + " = " + val[1] );
}
```

**EDITED**

There is also a bug with path construction, and the variables `level` and `curLevel` are not necessary.
Here is a code example that works :

```
public static void processChildNode(NodeList listOfNodes, String tags) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if (listOfNodes.item(i) instanceof Element) {
            String tagPath = tags + "." + listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeName();
            if (listOfNodes.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength() >= 1) {
                processChildNode(listOfNodes.item(i).getChildNodes(),
                        tagPath);
            }

        } else if (listOfNodes.item(i) instanceof Text
                && listOfNodes.getLength() == 1) {
            String value = listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            valueList.add(new String[] { tags, value });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering. Now it show all branches, but paths still incorrect:

Comment: RootNode.Node_11 = LEVEL_1-Value_1
RootNode.Node_12 = LEVEL_1-Value_2
RootNode.Node_13.Node_121 = LEVEL_2-Value_1
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231.Node_12341 = LEVEL_4-Value_1
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231 = LEVEL_4-Value_2
RootNode.Node_14.Node_121.Node_1231 = LEVEL_4-Value_3
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25.Node_251 = Value_251
RootNode.Node_15.Node_25 = Value_252
RootNode.Node_15.Node_251 = Value_253
RootNode.Node_15 = Value_254
RootNode.Node_15.Node_251 = Value_255
RootNode.Node_15 = Value_256
RootNode.Node_15.Node_251 = Value_257
RootNode.Node_15 = Value_258

Comment: You have a bug with `tagPath += "." + listOfNodes.item(i).getNodeName();` and the variables `level` and `curlevel` are not necessary. See my edited answer for code example.

Comment: Super Chafouin can you help me one more time. I cannot use recursion here. Is there the way to do same without recursion? Thanks.

Comment: I have done an example without recursion, you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/wzPk5ruL). Basically, we have list of nodes to process. We get the first node of the list and we add its children to the list. We also build a Map that associate each node with its path in the XML.

Comment: Hi Super, can you please tell me where can I get XMLStringParser? is it needed any jar? Is it same as DocumentBuilder.parse?

Comment: Hi Surodip, yes it should be : `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(...)`