# Java: How to get xml nodes path without recursion

Tags: java, xml

I asked this question yesterday and got great help from Super Chafouin
[Java: How to get xml nodes path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182420/java-how-to-get-xml-nodes-path)

However. I cannot use recursion here. Is there a way to do the same job without recursion? 
I really need help with this one. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You certainly can convert the recursive solution to a looping solution with Stack.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why can you not use recursion? What constraint requires you to do if differently?

Comment: I'm not very experienced, could you help me with example?

Comment: I was told that it must be done without recursion.

Comment: "I was told to do it this way" isn't good enough. A professional engineer needs to investigate the true requirements that underpin the stated requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The other comment looks so weird to me as it is copying same logic again and again.

It is hard not to use recursion IF you are using DOM.  However, there are other kind of XML parser.

your task is straight-forward with a StAX parser (I believe using SAX is equally simple).

The idea is simple:

1. Have a stack to store the current "path" (Let me call it path stack)
2. When you encounter start of node, push the name of that node to the path stack
3. When you encounter end of node, pop from the path stack
4. When you encounter a text node, print out the values in the path stack, and the text value itself

I believe the instruction should be clear enough and I believe a average programmer should be able to figure out the actual code by the logic described above.

Comment: I never used  StAX parser, could you post example suitable to my case?

Comment: Have you ever tried to search for that yourself?  I believe the hints are clear enough.  What makes it so difficult for you just type "stax xml parser example" in google?

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
// create a document
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document document = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse("input.xml");

// XPath selecting all leaf nodes (assumes all leaf nodes contain a value)
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[count(./descendant::*)=1]");

// list of all nodes containing a value
NodeList list = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    // store node name and value
    Node node = list.item(i);
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(node.getNodeName());
    String value = node.getTextContent();

    // traverse all parents and prepend their names to path
    node = node.getParentNode();
    while (node.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        path.insert(0, node.getNodeName() + '.');
        node = node.getParentNode();
    }

    System.out.println(path + " = " + value);
}
```

Comment: Slanec thanks a lot. Just tested your code and it works great.

Comment: @klipa I'm glad I could help. If you had any additional questions about the code, fire away!

Comment: The only things - in reality I need nodes path and value in separate fields in order to insert them into database. And I'm not quite sure how to access them from output row by row, like it was in my yesterday post, where they were stored in ArrayList in  {tagPath, value} pare.

Comment: @klipa I edited my code so that now you have `path` and `value` separated in the end. I hope now it's trivial to store it instead of printing it ;).